# Pulling certain information from Json

Tags: php, json

I've recently been exploring the Xbox API over at XboxAPI.com to try and increase my knowledge and confidence of actually using API's and also using Json Data. I found some code on another question that I had a play around with and got it to give me something back, the code I am currently using is:

```
$url     = 'https://xboxapi.com/v2/2745051201447500/presence';
$headers = array(
    'X-AUTH: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Visiting the page in the browser gives me the following:

```
{"xuid":2745051201447500,"state":"Online","devices":[{"type":"XboxOne","titles":[{"id":714681658,"name":"Home","placement":"Background","state":"Active","lastModified":"2014-10-07T22:02:34.821235Z"},{"id":446059611,"activity":{"richPresence":"In a Street Race."},"name":"Forza Horizon 2","placement":"Full","state":"Active","lastModified":"2014-10-07T22:02:34.821235Z"}]}]}
```

My question is, how do I pull certain bits of information out of the above? For example if I wanted to pull the "name" and just display that, how would I go about doing that? I've tried a couple of things including the following:

```
echo $result->devices[0]->type;
```

but that didn't work. I don't know how far off I am from the correct answer, but would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, do a json_decode like below which will put into an associate array.

Then, you would need also to make sure you use an index on those that are multidimensional as noted below.

And voilla - basically, you're missing the json_decode.

```
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
$result->devices[0]->type;
```

Ugh - also forgot

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

You're curl is not outputting to a string variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply airtech. Unfortunately the only thing I'm still seeing in the browser is just the Json. Your code above should display "Xbox One", right?

Comment: Yes it should, and yes it does.

Comment: Can you do a var_dump(json_decode(curl_exec($ch)))?

Comment: I've added var_dump(json_decode(curl_exec($ch))) but it's still just showing the Json in the exact same format as before.

Comment: Just corrected my answer - forgot to change the output of curl to output to astring

Comment: Thanks airtech. That line you just added to your answer, is that supposed to replace "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);" which is what I already have in my code? If I do that, then it won't be using my authentication key and I won't get any data back.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed your question - if you hadn't figured it out; no, you add this to your options.  You don't replace the line you have.

Comment: Ah yeah I figured it out about 10 minutes after posting my previous comment. Have marked your answer as the accepted answer, thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you will need some akin to json_decode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
  :
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch);
echo $result->devices->titles->name;
```

Note: The above has not been tested.

Answer (score 0):

`devices` is an array (note the `[]` in the JSON), so you need

```
$result->devices[0]->type // XboxOne
                ^^^
```

The same will hold for `titles` - that's also an array and would need `[]` dereferencing in PHP. a `var_dump($result)` would show you a nicely formatted structured dump of the array, and show you you exactly what "path" you need to use to get any to any piece of data in it.

Comment: Thanks for replying Marc B. I have added what you suggested however I'm still getting exactly the same in the browser, it's not performing the echo. I've edited my original question with the new code I'm using. Thanks again.